# Find and Replace System folder path to Web path in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of records stored with System path.

```
|x\MainFolder\SubFolder\File1.abc |xSome\string|xOther\String
|y\MainFolder\SubFolder\File2.abc |ySome\string|yOther\String
```

**Output**

```
|x/MainFolder/SubFolder/File1.abc |xSome\string|xOther\String
|y/MainFolder/SubFolder/File2.abc |ySome\string|yOther\String
```

So, I need to replace exactly the system file path to web based path. I know its NOT mandatory as the browsers can treat the `\` as `/` But still I need to do it for consistency of my data.

Please advise.

Comment: Is suggesting [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) too obvious?

Comment: Can you show more formats (e.g. all edge cases)? Or will it always be this number of characters, or at least always be two strings, the first one needs to have the replacement, the second one doesn't?

Comment: @DonMax So you only want to replace the slashes in the first half of your value?

Comment: Maybe I can keep `/MainFolder` as the first and the full stop character as the last 1 to find, Replace and update it.

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes, I need to update the slashes only in this block `\MainFolder\SubFolder\File1.abc`

Comment: Note that your question makes it unclear what your rows actually look like. I assumed `|` was separating individual columns (in which case the solution is trivial), but it sounds like it's the value of one single column (which is slightly more involved). From 2016 onwards, `STRING_SPLIT` comes in handy for such cases.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There can be multiple `|` characters in a single string and the same cannot be used for splitting the substring.

Comment: The number of `|` isn't relevant, what matters is whether you can tell which string needs replacing. E.g. `SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) = 2 THEN REPLACE(value, '\', '/') ELSE value END FROM STRING_SPLIT('|x\MainFolder\SubFolder\File1.abc |xSome\string|xOther\String', '|')` (this intrinsically sucks because `STRING_SPLIT` has no ordinal and adding one after the fact is dubious, but you get my point -- if you knew the path always had `.` it'd be easier to get consistent).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sample data, I would simply find the FIRST 'dot', and perform a little string manipulation.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SystemPath varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('|x\MainFolder\SubFolder\File1.abc |xSome\string|xOther\String')
,('|y\MainFolder\SubFolder\File2.abc |ySome\string|yOther\String')

Select replace(left(SystemPath,charindex('.',SystemPath+'.')),'\','/')
       + substring(SystemPath,charindex('.',SystemPath+'.')+1,len(SystemPath))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
|x/MainFolder/SubFolder/File1.abc |xSome\string|xOther\String
|y/MainFolder/SubFolder/File2.abc |ySome\string|yOther\String
```